# Sending voice command automatically to google home

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I want to test how Google Home transforms vocal commands to text by sending voice commands and storing the result returned. I have already done the storage part, but now, I can't find in the documentation how to send automatically voice commands to google home, the only apparent way is to speak to it directly, which not very practical if you want to test a long list of commands, 50 times for each command!

**Edited:** To make it clearer, I want to write a function that sends voice files (mp3, or any other format) to google assistant, instead of having to say/pronounce the command in a human way.

Do you know if it is possible to make this process automatic ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want the [Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/), which will let you send an audio stream/file or text to be processed by the Assistant and return the result.

You're unclear about exactly what you're trying to do, and how you're trying to do it, but [this table](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview#features) should help you understand what features are available for the various methods of using the Assistant SDK. In general, you'll be able to send an audio file or stream (either using the python library or a gRPC library for your language of choice) and get a response back.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. Can you please specify the function / part / guide to do this? I have been through the Assistant SDK but I'm not able to find it.

Comment: Answer updated, but I really can't provide much additional info since you were fairly vague about how you were trying to do this.

Comment: Thank you @Prisoner for the update. I will check the Assistant SDK in details and mark the question as answered if I find an answer.
Enjoy your holidays :)

Comment: Hi @Prisoner, I have read almost everything about Google Assistant SDK and I didn't find anything to solve my problem. It seems that the SDK is designed for hardware makers who want to add google assistants on their gadgets.
But what I'm trying to do is to write a function that sends a voice file to google assistant instead of talking directly to it in a human way.

Comment: The SDK is software (again, either a python library or a gRPC interface for you to build a library for your language) that lets you send a voice file. While it is mostly for hardware developers, there is nothing stopping other software developers from using it.